# Dynamic Assignment of jobs to processors on a set of shared resources

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, parallel-processing, scheduling, job-scheduling

### Problem

I have a collection of objects that I want to process parallely. Each object is comprised of a set of sub-objects. The restriction is that no two objects which share a common sub-object can be processed at the same time.

I think this should be a standard problem. If somebody could guide me to the right set of readings that would be good enough for me.

### Example

*Objects:* {AB}, {CD}, {EF}, {BD}, {FA}

So {AB} and {BD} cannot be run in parallel since they share the resource B.

### Naive thoughts

***Greedy Thought:***

Main thread keeps a set of currently active/in-process sub-objects. If the next object to be processed does not share any resource from the active set then allocate the work or else push the work-packet at the back of the queue of objects so that it can be processed at a later time. The main thread set would have to be locked and everything.

***Partitioning thoughts***

I thought of partitioning the objects into sets that ensure that the objects between sets are mutually exclusive. For example, create a graph of dependencies, so create edge btw AB --> BD since they share a resource. Then process all the disconnected sub-graphs in parallel.
but this would not be very load balanced and might not be very efficient..

- Is there a standard parallel pattern to this?
- Each thread locking the sub-objects before processing should be trivial. I am looking for something that can minimize locking.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is your objective function?

Comment: what do you mean by objective function ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Minimum processing time? Maximum load balance?

Comment: I want to minimize the time taken to process the complete collection of objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use [tbb](/questions/tagged/tbb)::[flow::graph](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/flow_graph/primary_components.htm), where objects are represented by [queue_nodes](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/flow_graph/queue_node_cls.htm), tasks are expressed by [function_nodes](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/flow_graph/func_node_cls.htm), and the dependencies are connected through [join_nodes](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/flow_graph/join_node_cls.htm) similar to [how solved](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2011/01/10/using-the-intel-threading-building-blocks-graph-community-preview-feature-an-implementation-of-dining-philosophers) the [Dinning Philosophers problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem) which looks like a subset of your more general problem statement. The following diagram represents tasks like [AB] [BC] [CD] [DA]:

[image: Dinning Philosophers using TBB Flow Graph]

> The pictire is taken from [this blog](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2011/01/10/using-the-intel-threading-building-blocks-graph-community-preview-feature-an-implementation-of-dining-philosophers)

Comment: +1 just for linking to the problem. I wish I could do another +1 for the tbb references. I may have read this sometime back! Thanks for reminding. Let me read more now. :)